# Parse data from JProfiler 13 Heap Walker Outgoing References

Tags: jprofiler

I am trying to parse data (Heap Walker outgoing references) from the snapshot obtained by offline profiling.
Is that even possible without using GUI? The entire process must be fully automated.

I already tried converting the snapshot to xml and extracting the data from it, but there is no Heap Walker data that is needed. Also, i tried to export the view from the snapshot using the command line, but there is no option for Heap Walker outgoing references.
Do you have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0):

As of JProfiler 14.x, heap walker data in JProfiler is not available programmatically.